# How to check for empty EditText in all sublayouts of main layout?

Tags: android, is-empty, textedit

I have few EditText in my LinearLayout. This EditText are in different subLayouts.
How can I check all my EditText on my id/main_layout for empty?

*And one important thing - in process of work there will appear new. So, I should find
all EditText automaticaly, I can't get it by it's id.*

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title_tile_size"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Tile size:" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/inp_tile_width"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="cm"
            android:inputType="number" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/inp_tile_height"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="cm"
            android:inputType="number" >
        </EditText>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_for_sides"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_one_side"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/inp_side_width"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="cm"
                android:inputType="number" >

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/inp_side_height"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="cm"
                android:inputType="number" >
            </EditText>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: if (TextUtils.isEmpty(edittext.getText().toString())) {
   return true;
  }
  return false;

Comment: do you mean you want to loop through all edit boxes inside your root layout and just check for empty and not writing if condition for individual edit text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
View parent = findViewById(R.id.parent_layout);

for(int i = 0; i < parent.getChildCount(); i++) {
View singleChild = parent.getChildAt(i);
    if(singleChild instanceof EditText) {
        //Support for EditText
        EditText mEditText = (EditText)singleChild;
        if(mEditText.getText().length() >  0){
            Log.i("TAG", mEditText.getText().toString());
        } else{
            Log.i("TAG", "EditText is NULL");
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:

This method will recursively traverse down through a layout hierarchy, including all layouts nested therein, and return the number of empty `EditText`s. The `ViewGroup root` parameter is the top layout where you want the search to begin, corresponding to `parent` in the above example.

```
public int getEmptyEditTextCount(ViewGroup root)
{
    int empty = 0;
    int childCount = root.getChildCount();

    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++)
    {
        View v = root.getChildAt(i);

        if (v instanceof EditText
            && TextUtils.isEmpty(((EditText) v).getText().toString()))
        {
            empty++;
        }
        else if (v instanceof ViewGroup)
        {
            empty += getEmptyEditTextCount((ViewGroup) v);
        }
    }

    return empty;
}
```

Comment: @MikeM. you can, above or below the answer. with a small `EDIT:`

Answer (score 2):

just create an `List<EditText>`, fill it with the ones from the XML with `findById()`,  and the ones added dinamicall, `add()` them at creation time

Answer (score 0):

Here You check EditText is empty or not

```
EditText1 inp_tile_height = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.inp_tile_height)
EditText1 inp_side_height = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.inp_side_height)
```

In click or other wherever you want put this code

```
String s1 = inp_tile_height.getText().toString().trim();
if(s1.isEmpty()){

    // empty edittext
    return;

}

String s2 = inp_side_height.getText().toString().trim();
if(s2.isEmpty()){

    // empty edittext
    return;

}
```

Comment: This presumes that I know id of EditText, but I can't. Because in process of work of the application there will appear new EditText.

Comment: ok then how you insert new EditText runtime? Please append that code in question section area

Answer (score 0):

check this out

```
    EditText usernameEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editUsername);
sUsername = usernameEditText.getText().toString();
if (sUsername.matches("")) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "You did not enter a username", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return;
}
```

I hope that's help

Comment: This presumes that I know id of EditText, but I can't. Because in process of work of the application there will appear new EditText.

Comment: While generating new Edit text you can provide them Id  
EditText editText = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
                editText.setId(editText.generateViewId());
                editText.setHeight(50);
                editText.setWidth(50);
                ll.addView(editText);
you can use a loop to generate the id like 
for(int i=0;i<5;i++) editText.setId("editText"+i);
Now you can recognize and check as amar says.